# Authentication using AngularJs and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, ionic-framework

I want to implement authentication in my application, and I don't know how check name and password entered by the user to be the same as the one in the database,  and I don't know how the query in php file must be.
in the database of Table 'client', I have NomClient and mdp(password).

**login.html**

```
<ion-content class="padding" ng-controller="loginCtrl">
<div class="list list-inset" >
<label class="item item-input">
      <input type="text" placeholder="nom" required="" ng-model="NomClient"> 
</label> 
<label class="item item-input">
      <input type="password" placeholder="Password" ng-model="mdp"> 
</label> 
    <button class="button button-block button-positive" ng-click="submit()">Login</button>       
 </ion-content>
```

**app.js**

```
app.controller('loginCtrl', function($scope,$state,$http){
  $scope.submit= function(){
    $http.post(  
                "http://localhost/deb/login.php",  
                {
                'NomClient':$scope.NomClient,
                'mdp':$scope.mdp
                }  
           ).success(function(data){  
           }

  };
```

**login.php**

```
 <?php    
 $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "tem");  

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
if(count($data) > 0)  
 {  
$NomClient = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $data->N);NomClient
$mdp = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$data->mdp);


$query =("??");
$que = mysqli_query($con, $query);
$count = mysqli_num_rows($que);

if($count==1){
echo 'correct';}
else{
echo 'wrong';
}

}
 ?>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: MD5 is not sufficient for password hashing. Use [`password_hash()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You required this query in php  like this
you insert password convert md5 like as query without query you can remove md5 function .

```
     $convertmd5 = md5($mdp);
     $query ="SELECT * FROM `youtblname` where NomClient ='$NomClient' and mdp='$convertmd5'";
```

Comment: it s a simple selection, what I want is check if username and password of user are the same as the one in the database. Thank you

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. You should use [**mysqli**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [**PDO**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) prepared statements with bound parameters as described in [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Answer (score 0):

```
$response['status'] = 0;
$response['message'] = '';

$NomClient = $_POST['NomClient'];
$mdp = md5($_POST['mdp']);

$query = 'SELECT * FROM `client` WHERE NomClient = "'.$NomClient.'" AND   mdp= "'.$mdp.'"';

$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "tem");
if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
    $response['status'] = 0;
    $response['message'] = "Failed to connect to MySQL: ".mysqli_connect_error();
    echo jsone_encode($response);exit;
}

$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
$rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);
if($rowcount>0){
    $response['status'] = 1;
    $response['message'] = 'Login successful';
}
else{
    $response['status'] = 0;
    $response['message'] = 'Invalid username of password';
}

echo json_encode($response);exit;
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. You should use [**mysqli**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [**PDO**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) prepared statements with bound parameters as described in [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: I never use core php. I use codeigniter and laravel framework. Just because the question is for core php, and need help regarding the query. I helped it out. @AlexHowansky

Comment: @NIRAV , thank you, i try it, I made some temptation but It doesn't generate anything, any message and I can't log in.

Comment: @SalamSalam I tried out but working fine in my system. Can you please try it again? and If there is minor syntax error, please take of it your self. If any major changes related let me know.

Comment: @NIRAV! please did you implement  also the angularJS code and it worked! Or you just tried the .php file . Thank you

Comment: @SalamSalam only php. Because your angularjs code $http.post() will pass $_POST variables to server. Buy yes, there is closing parenthesis **)** is missing after .success(function(data){} **)** . and Use inspect element->network to inspect the request and response.